# Jquery flickering when I add classes to my divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with Jquery and flickering. My problem is this, when I convert my id's to classes the below syntax isn't working. The problem is, it flickers. It flickers approx. 7-8 times. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

I would also like to add when I change my classes to ID's everything works great but only one item on my webpage has the ability of hide>click>slideToggle (which isn't what I want because I'm listing more than one item per page for sale). This syntax is below as well, it's very similar to the syntax that does not work but I've decided to include it anyway.

(Not working syntax. Has classes)

```
<?php
echo "<div class=\"fmv2\">Your Name</div>";
?>

<div class="p122">

<?php

 echo form_open("submit/submit_info");

 echo form_label('Your Name:','name');

   $data = array(
    "name" => 'name',
 "id" => 'box_width',
 "value" => set_value('name')
   );

   echo form_input($data);

   echo '<br>';

   echo form_submit('Submit','Submit');

   echo form_close(); 

?>
</div>
```

My Jquery (Not working, has classes)

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".p122").hide(function(){

    $(".fmv2").click(function() {

      $(".p122").slideToggle(300);

  });

 });

});
```

Working syntax (Has Ids)

```
<?php
echo "<div id=\"fmv2\">Your Name</div>";
?>

<div id="p122">

<?php

 echo form_open("submit/submit_info");

 echo form_label('Your Name:','name');

   $data = array(
    "name" => 'name',
 "id" => 'box_width',
 "value" => set_value('name')
   );

   echo form_input($data);

   echo '<br>';

   echo form_submit('Submit','Submit');

   echo form_close(); 

?>
</div>
```

My Jquery. (Working, has Ids)

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#p122").hide(function(){

    $("#fmv2").click(function() {

      $("#p122").slideToggle(300);

  });

 });

});
```

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – first of all, you are showing us _server-side_ code, while you want to discuss a _client-side_ problem. Please show the actual HTML code the client receives – your PHP code is of absolutely no interest here.

Comment: @CBroe I figured out the answer to my own question. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I've been playing around with the syntax and the below code works.

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
      $('div.p122').hide();
      $('div.fmv2').click(function() {
            $(this).next('div.p122').slideToggle(300);
      });
});
```